# How to work around incorrect (?) TypeScript/DefinitelyTyped typings for PouchDB?

Tags: typescript, pouchdb, typescript-typings, definitelytyped

I'm looking for help with TypeScript and the [PouchDB type declarations](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/pouchdb). Consider this TS code:

```
import PouchDB = require('pouchdb')
import find = require('pouchdb-find')
PouchDB.plugin(find)

const data = new PouchDB("http://localhost:5984/data"),

export async function deleteLastRevForIds(dbname, ids) {
  const docsToDelete = await data.find({
    fields: ["_id", "_rev"],
    selector: { _id: { $in: ids } }
  })

  const deletePromise = docsToDelete.docs.map(doc => {
    return data.remove(doc) // <-- HERE TSC SHOUTS AT ME about `doc`
  })
  const deletion = await Promise.all(deletePromise)
  return deletion
}
```

At the annotated `remove()` call, `tsc` emits this error:

```
Argument of type 'IdMeta' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RemoveDocument'.
  Type 'IdMeta' is not assignable to type 'RevisionIdMeta'.
    Property '_rev' is missing in type 'IdMeta'.'
```

What's happening is that the `find()` call is [typed by the DefinitelyTyped typings](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/pouchdb-find/index.d.ts#L166)
as returning a `{docs: PouchDB.Core.IdMeta[]}`. And as its name implies,
a [PouchDB.Core.IdMeta[]](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/pouchdb-core/index.d.ts#L69-L74) means an array of `{_id: string}`.

But it's false! `PouchDB.find()` doesn't return just a list of `{_id: ...}` objects,
it returns a list of `{_id: ..., _rev: ...}` (plus I asked for these two fields explicitly). Or am I missing something?

As a result, when calling the `remove()` function (correctly typed by the DT typings as
needing an fully-specified _id+_rev `RevisionIdMeta`) with such an object, TS rightly shouts at me.

I tried casting this thing in all directions but couldn't bend it to my will; `tsc` keeps erroring that `_rev` is missing from my object.

- Is there a way for me do such a "deep" cast?
- If not, is there a way to override the DT typings as locally as possible?
- Should I be doing something else entirely?

Also, should I propose a change to the DT typings?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, the Pouchdb-find definitions are wrong. Something like this should get you moving...

```js
const data = new PouchDB("http://localhost:5984/data")

interface FixedFindResponse<Content extends PouchDB.Core.Encodable> {
  docs: PouchDB.Core.ExistingDocument<Content>[];
}
export async function deleteLastRevForIds(dbname: void, ids: number[]) {
  const docsToDelete: FixedFindResponse<any> = await data.find({
    fields: ["_id", "_rev"],
    selector: { _id: { $in: ids } }
  })

  const deletePromise = docsToDelete.docs.map(doc => {
    return data.remove(doc) // <-- HERE TSC SHOUTS AT ME about `doc`
  })
  const deletion = await Promise.all(deletePromise)
  return deletion
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way for me do such a "deep" cast?

You can always re-cast something using `as any as Whatever`. Obviously, this should be a last resort if you can't get the types correct, because there's no safety around the assertion whatsoever. For example `123 as any as Window` compiles.

> is there a way to override the DT typings as locally as possible?

Yes, take a look at [Declaration Merging: Module Augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation).

> Should I be doing something else entirely?

If you're sure the type definitions are wrong you could always patch them and submit a PR to DefinitelyTyped.